# Создание карты местности

Tags: алгоритм, html, php, html5, javascript

Необходимо реализовать функционал гугловских карт, т.е. зум карты. Подскажите где можно почитать про алгоритм составления подобных приложений, возможно готовую расписанную реализацию.

Это будет веб-приложение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете посмотреть как устроена вот эта штука: leafletjs.com — это по клиентской части.
По серверу можно начать отсюда: [Tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles).
Вот ещё интересный продукт из этой темы: [Map SDK](http://cloudmade.com/products/map-sdk)